# "TargetPlatform.fuchsia is not yet supported by the maps plugin" this text is displayed instead of google map using google_maps_flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-flutter

I'm trying to use **google_maps_flutter** package but **TargetPlatform.fuchsia is not yet supported by the maps plugin** is displayed instead of the map, I'm not receiving any error in the console. I have added the meta-data entry containing the API key to `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `android/app/src/main`.

[received message instead of the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SObS.png)

below is my code.

```
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: The message is so clear. Fushia is not yet support by the plugin

Comment: what fuchsia is exactly? I have tried the package in another project and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It worked in the same device ?

Comment: yes it was in the same device.

Comment: try clean build the project, apparently the plugin somehow `"thinks"` that it is being run on the Fushia Platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a line of code in `main.dart`:

`debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride = TargetPlatform.fuchsia;`

I commented it out and the problem fixed.