# "TargetPlatform.windows is not yet supported by the maps plugin" - How to solve this

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, android-emulator

I'm just trying to get Google Maps displayed on my emulator and I also used **google_maps_flutter** package but `TargetPlatform.windows` is not yet supported by the maps plugin is displayed instead of the map, I'm not receiving any error in the console.

I have added the meta-data entry containing the API key to `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `android/app/src/main`.

[image: Click this to see the output]

Please help me to solve this?

Comment: As per this  https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter : its only works for ios and android only.

Comment: Are you running this on an Android emulator?

Comment: @HardikMehta yes ive enabled the maps sdk api for android as well as ios too

Comment: @mkobuolys i was trying it with my emulator at first, due to some reason suddenly it stopped working and now im running it in chrome web

Comment: As @HardikMehta mentioned, that's exactly the problem - the package does not support this platform.

Comment: ok then ill try making my emulator work and run on it, i hope it works there

Comment: Could you please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463938/targetplatform-fuchsia-is-not-yet-supported-by-the-maps-plugin-this-text-is-di) post?

Answer (score 3):

add in dependencies:

```
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.3.2+2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe the issue will be with your Maps Api key, remove all the restrictions of your api key from Google Cloud Platform , just like this
[image: Edit Maps Api]

Comment: i tried removing the restriction.. still it shows the same

Comment: on which device you are testing?

Comment: for now im testing it in chrome web. coz all of a sudden my emulator stopped working

Comment: that's why it is showing error. test it on any android device or emulator

Answer (score 0):

Either you're trying to run your project on Windows platform (meaning you did not choose an Android Emulator or phone in the run device menu, see example below)
[image]

or, if your screenshot is from a Android device, there's something messed up with your project configuration. You can try running `flutter create .` in the terminal to recreate your project, or you can create a new one from the scratch (watch out for which platform you activate, see below) and then import the code.

[image]

Screenshots are from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue while compiling for Web, I found a solution here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-and-google-maps-f2489b483a1f

Quoted:
My app was using the Google Maps for Flutter plugin, which does not support Web “out of the box”. I got the following error message: TargetPlatform.windows is not yet supported by the maps plugin.

“Not yet” indicates that this will change in the future, but for now, I had to add the google_maps_flutter_web plugin. I added it to pubspec.yaml:

google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.10
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.1.0+8
An import statement for google_maps_flutter_web.dart was not needed.

I then enabled the Maps JavaScript API.

The original app was using the Maps SDK for Android. The web version needs the Maps JavaScript API. I could use the same API key, which for Android is in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml. I went to the Google Cloud API Library and enabled my key for the Maps JavaScript API. The Maps SDK for Android is free, the Maps JavaScript API is not (but there is a generous free tier that can be used during testing), so I had also to enable billing and provide payment info.

I added the following line to web/index.html, right after the script that starts the service worker (zzzz..zzz is my API key):

When I did

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit
```